Error creating bean with name 'refreshEventListener' after upgraded to Java 21 and SpringBoot 3.2.4
Recently I am upgrading our application to Java 21 Spring Boot 3.2.4 and Now I end up with an exception which is clueless.
All the migration were done using openWrite receipe
The exception which I am facing
2024-06-20 14:01:40 GMT | WARN | o.h.d.Dialect                  | 353 | restartedMain : HHH000511: The 10.1.0 version for [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect] is no longer supported, hence certain features may not work properly. The minimum supported version is 12.0.0. Check the community dialects project for available legacy versions.
2024-06-20 14:01:40 GMT | WARN | letWebServerApplicationContext | 632 | restartedMain : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL82Dialect
2024-06-20 14:01:40 GMT | INFO | c.z.h.HikariDataSource         | 350 | restartedMain : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-06-20 14:01:40 GMT | INFO | c.z.h.HikariDataSource         | 352 | restartedMain : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-06-20 14:01:40 GMT | WARN | tationConfigApplicationContext | 133 | restartedMain : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'refreshEventListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:265) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:222) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:457) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:384) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) [spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093) [spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.destroy(NamedContextFactory.java:113) [spring-cloud-context-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211) [spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587) [spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559) [spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1202) [spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520) [spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1195) [spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1186) [spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:637) [spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at com.airbus.argo.ArgoA320DataServiceApplication.main(ArgoA320DataServiceApplication.java:53) [classes/:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) [spring-boot-devtools-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
2024-06-20 14:01:40 GMT | INFO | o.a.c.c.StandardService        | 173 | restartedMain : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-06-20 14:01:40 GMT | ERROR | o.s.b.SpringApplication        | 851 | restartedMain : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL82Dialect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:895) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:848) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:265) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:222) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:621) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at com.airbus.argo.ArgoA320DataServiceApplication.main(ArgoA320DataServiceApplication.java:53) [classes/:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) [spring-boot-devtools-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>21</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    <argo.commons.version>1.2.4_GADLU</argo.commons.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-rev-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>8.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.airbus.argo.rdl</groupId>
        <artifactId>wli-commons</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>33.0.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>/home/jenkins/.m2/argo-style.xml</configLocation>
                <checkstyleXmlOutput>true</checkstyleXmlOutput>
                <checkstyleXmlOutputDirectory>target</checkstyleXmlOutputDirectory>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                <excludes>**/module-info.java,**/package-info.java</excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                <release>${java.version}</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

Database Connection
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

And we are handling the database entity with different service and I will attach the pom.xml for that service too
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmln
    <version>0.0.9</version>
    <name>wli-commons</name>
    <description>wli commons</description>    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I am having be blocked with this issue more that a week. I will be thankful for all the response.

Rather than copy-pasting parts in their entirity, please edit your question to include the absolute bare minimum - remove as much as you can while still getting the error so it is useful to future visitors.

It seems you have been using incorrect hibernate-related dependencies.
I added the following in your pom.xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

rather than the hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55 you had included.
The reason is that spring boot starter jpa 3.2.4 comes with:
org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.4.4.Final
(take note of https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils readme)
The complete pom.xml I used to get the application working with a PostgreSQL server 16 is as follows, after editing to remove some syntax errors, redundant or erroneous dependencies. Note I removed consul and actuator to make the task easier; they are not relevant.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
        <argo.commons.version>1.2.4_GADLU</argo.commons.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
            <artifactId>qpid-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-rev-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>8.18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>33.0.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Thanks @N Sarj it is working fine and you saved my weekend.
